# OpenAPI generator for NextJS

Tags: typescript, next.js, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I have a NextJS project which uses the /api path for implementation of our API. We use an openapi.yaml file to define the interface. The following command generates the API client and works great:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -i data/api/openapi.yaml -o src/api/openapi -g typescript-fetch
```

I am now trying to generate the stubs for implementing the server side of the API (which should be called under the /api). I tried the following which shows an error:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -i data/api/openapi.yaml -o src/api/openapi -g next
```

This is because it cannot find a 'next' generator:

> Can't load config class with name 'next' Available: ... here comes a
> list of generators

I noticed that there is a typescript-node generator but my project uses Next.JS and not plain node. Is there a way to re-use the node generator or another way?

Answer (score 0):

As of 21th of September 2023 there is no server generator for Next.js.

It is not possible to reuse that standard Node generator without heavy alterations.

You can find a list of server generators in the [documentation](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/#server-generators).